# binary representation of a float

Tags: c++, double

why this two call to toBinary function compute the same output (at least under VS2010) ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

template<class T> bitset<sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT> toBinary(const T num) 
{
    bitset<sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT> mybits;
    const char * const p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&num);
    for (int i = sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT-1 ; i >= 0 ; --i)
        mybits.set(i, (*(p)&(1<<i) ));
    return mybits;
}

int main() 
{
    cout << toBinary(8.9).to_string() << "\n"; 
    cout << toBinary( 8.9 + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() ).to_string()  << "\n"; 
    cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That epsilon is relative to 1; here, instead, you are summing it to 8.9, which is more than 8 (2^3) times bigger than 1. This means that that epsilon would change a binary digit that is three digits to the right of the rightest digit stored in that double.

If you want to notice something change, you have to add at about 8.9*epsilon.

Comment: which value should I add to get the smallest increment, because if I add 8.8 for instance, I also get a change?

Comment: There is no single value that does what you want, but there is a library function - see my answer.

Comment: Hmmm, I too tested it and got that result, I think it depends on the exact internal representation of the number. A good rule of thumb is that `number*epsilon` gets you a value that, added to `number`, will *certainly* change it, while under it you don't have guarantees.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems.  The first is that your `toBinary` function doesn't do what you wanted -- it should read like so (assuming a little-endian CPU):

```
template<class T> bitset<sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT> toBinary(const T num)
{
    bitset<sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT> mybits;
    const char * const p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&num);
    for (int i = sizeof(T)-1; i >= 0; i--)
        for (int j = CHAR_BIT-1; j >= 0; j--)
            mybits.set(i*CHAR_BIT + j, p[i] & (1 << j));
    return mybits;
}
```

The other problem is as Matteo describes: `numeric_limits<double>::epsilon` is the difference between `1.0` and the next larger representable value, not the difference between *any* floating point number and the next larger representable value.  You can see this for yourself by modifying your program to try incrementing `0.5`, `1.0`, and `2.0` -- adding `epsilon` will increment the *second*-to-last bit of `0.5`, the last bit of `1.0`, and have no effect on `2.0`.

There is a way to do what you're trying to do, though: the [`nextafter`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nextafter) family of functions (they're part of C99).

Comment: i don't get why ma function has a error.According to me (*(p)&(1<<i) will test each bit ? no ?

Comment: No, it wont.  `*p` has type `char`, so it retrieves either the first or the last `CHAR_BIT` bits of your `double` (depending on endianness), and *only* those bits.  So most of your loop is not reading bit `i` of the `double`, but a sign-extension copy of bit 7.  To see the second and subsequent bytes of the `double`, you have to offset `p` *before* dereferencing it, which is what my modified loop does.

Comment: I don't get why it's (1<<j) and not (1<<i)

Comment: Because `i` is the *byte* index.  Each loop iteration needs to access the bit at `i*CHAR_BIT + j` within the original value.  If it used `1<<i`, it wouldn't read every bit.

Comment: what is it not natural for me it is that for two differents bytes index (i=0 and i=8 for instance) we have the same mask (j=0)...so the mask doesn't match the correct position for i =0, at least in my mind...

Comment: You're still thinking about this as if we were operating on a giant bitfield containing the entire double.  We're not.  `p[i]` extracts a *single byte* from the double, at offset `i`; `& (1 << j)` extracts a bit *from that byte*, at offset `j`.  The bit numbers within each byte are always 0..(CHAR_BIT-1).

Comment: There is, for the record, no portable way to get a "giant bitfield containing the entire double".  This is how you have to do it, unless you like nasty tricks with unions.