# Convert 24 bit value to float and back

Tags: c#, floating-point

It is possible to convert `24 bit integer` value into `float` and then back to `24 bit integer` without losing data?

For example, let's consider 8 bit int, a byte, range is [-127..127] (we drop -128).

```
public static float ToFloatSample (byte x) { return x / 127f; }
```

So, if `x == -127`, result will be `-1`, if `x == 127`, result will be `1`. If `x == 64`, result will be `~0.5`

```
public static int ToIntSample (float x) { return (int) (x * 127f); }
```

So now:

```
int x = some_number;
float f = ToFloatSample (x);
int y = ToIntSample (f);
```

Will always `x == y` ? Using 8 bit int yes, but what if I use 24 bit?

Comment: What is the type of the source variable? "24-bit value" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: It mean that value have 2^24 possible values. For example 0..2^24 - 1.

Comment: Why not in an Int32? Looks like a much better fit.

Answer (score 1):

Having thought about your question, I now understand what you're asking.

I understand you have 24-bits which represent a real number `n` such that `-1 <= n <= +1` and you want to load this into an instance of `System.Single`, and back again.

In C/C++ this is actually quite easy with the `frexp` and `ldexp` functions, documented here ( [how can I extract the mantissa of a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672960/how-can-i-extract-the-mantissa-of-a-double) ), but in .NET it's a more involved process.

The C# language specification (and thusly, .NET) states it uses IEEE-754 1989 format, which means you'll need to dump the bits into an integer type so you can perform the bitwise logic to extract the components. This question has already been asked here on SO except for `System.Double` instead of `System.Single`, but converting the answer to work with `Single` is a trivial exercise for the reader ( [extracting mantissa and exponent from double in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389993/extracting-mantissa-and-exponent-from-double-in-c-sharp) ).

In your case, you'd want to store your 24-bit mantissa value in the low-24 bits of an `Int32` and then use the code in that linked question to load and extract it from a `Single` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Every integer in the range [-16777216, 16777216] is exactly representable as an IEEE 754 32-bit binary floating point number. That includes both the unsigned and 2's complement 24 bit integer ranges. Simple casting will do the job.

The range is wider than you would expect because there is an extra significand bit that is not stored - it is a binary digit that is known not to be zero.

Comment: The OP says he wants to store numbers between `-1` to `+1`, so not integers. Casting won't work in his case.